# javascript/jquery get lowest number

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("div").each(function(){
  var index_no = $(this).index();
  console.log(index_no);
});
```

I want to get lowest index but I can't do that

Comment: i have index numbers, like 2-4-1 i want to sort them like 1-2-4

and i have a dynamic system when click button i get random index numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get lowest index but I can't do that

Sure you can: `0`

The lowest index of any array is going to be 0 in JavaScript.

---

If you have an array of values, you can get the min as so:

```
var arr = [3,1,4];
Math.min.apply(Math, arr);  // returns 1
```

Given your codepen example (which you should include in your question):

```
var indexes = [];
$("div").each(function(i){
   if(!$(this).hasClass("lo")){
     indexes[indexes.length]=i;
   }
});


console.log("Matches: ", indexes);
console.log("Min: ", Math.min.apply(Math,indexes));
```

Comment: look, i have a each and i have a if in there if(!$(this).hasClass("bla")){
console.log($(this).index());
}

it's returns 2,5,7

i have to get 2 number

Comment: @Ugurcan you're confusing the index number with the value at that index number. If you have an array of numbers like [2, 5, 7], then array[0] will be 2.

Comment: @Ugurcan: do you see?

Comment: thank you, how can i get only first number? can you help me about that?

Comment: @Ugurcan I do not understand.  `indexes[0]` will return the first number in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you'll see that the `each` function provides the index number to the callback function you pass in.

Also, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish with your code, but isn't the lowest index of a collection going to be 0?

Comment: thanks, i have index numbers but i have to get lowest index number i can't sort them :S

Comment: I think you will need to provide more clarification as to what you mean by lowest index number.

Comment: i add a comment on the top

Comment: If you have the set of index numbers, why can't you just sort those numbers?

Comment: i don't know how can i do that

Comment: You can place those index numbers into an array and then sort the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<p>index_0</p>
<div>index_1</div>
<div>index_2</div>
<p>index_3</p>
<p>index_4</p>
<div>index_5</div>
<div>index_6</div>
<div>index_7</div>
```

**JS**

```
var cnt = 0;
var idxArray = [];

$("div").each(function(){
  var index_no = $(this).index();
  idxArray[cnt] = index_no;
    cnt++;
});
alert('The lowest index of DIV is [' + Math.min.apply(Math, idxArray) + ']');
```

**Working Example**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/188as6ks/1/)